# Unit testing controller functions making external HTTP requests in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Hi all so I've totally reworded this and included some code I produced. Normally I'd have tests for this first however I'm at a lost as to how to approach this.

I want to start off with unit tests for this function.

```
exports.getMatches = function(callback) {
  var url = "http://football-api.comapi/?Action=today&APIKey=" + secrets.APIKey + "&comp_id=1204";

  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) return (error);
        var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        var todaysMatches = parsedJSON.matches;
        var schedule = new Schedule({
          date: dates.today // external module
          matches: []
        });
        _.each(todaysMatches, function (match) {
          schedule.matches.push({
            match_id: match.match_id,
            match_time: match.match_time,
            match_localteam_id: match.match_localteam_id,
            match_localteam_name: match.match_localteam_name,
            match_visitorteam_id: match.match_visitorteam_id,
            match_visitorteam_name: match.match_visitorteam_name
          });
        });
        callback(schedule);
      });
    }
  ], function(schedule) {
    schedule.save(function (err) {
      if (err) return (err);
    });
    done();
  });
};
```

I'm really sorry for not providing any sort of headway because I'm just having a mental block here. There's only a few lines of code but there is so much going on and so much to test that I'm not sure where to start / what to mock / how to mock it.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm not sure how to write the test. I want to check that the list function has a variable `parsedJSON` that holds the data I mocked in the `match_in_array` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *sounds* like you are wanting to test `request()` and not your actual controller method.

Your unit test should evaluate whatever is passed to the `list()` callback, and determine if it has been transformed accordingly.

For example, if `list()` turns your JSON array into an HTML list `<ul><li /><li />...</ul>`, you should test the response/body output to determine if the transformation has been successful.

```
var mockJSON = [{id: 1, name: 'spinach'}];
var expected = '<ul><li data-id="1">spinach</li></ul>';
//...
matchController.list(function (error, response, body) {
  // something like this...
  expect(body).to.equal(expected);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might be getting a bit pedantic with my testing approach so thanks for the perspective. To give some context, I want to save the mockJSON to a database. So I guess that would be my "expected" variable in this sense. Would you recommend testing that the data is correct prior to saving it to the DB? Or just look it up in the database within the test?

Comment: Just as you are mocking your HTTP request, mock your database calls as well. By using a "fake" database, you can test to be sure that your data is being "stored" by your controller. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/nicholascloud/8f8a50506cd3077b2bd1

Comment: Hey Nicholas, I spent some time trying to implement your solution but couldn't work out how to test the logic in my code. I wrote the basic functionality first hoping that might give me some ideas for tests but that hasn't happened. I've included the code I have to test. Could you by any chance give me some pointers on how to start unit testing this? Thanks

Comment: @duketon Here is a possible solution that mocks the `Schedule` function (which is your data store here): https://gist.github.com/nicholascloud/b35a5d231602b968f343 (note the updated implementation starts on line 42 https://gist.github.com/nicholascloud/b35a5d231602b968f343#file-mock-db-test2-js-L42).

Comment: Its 1:37am and the notification woke me up but you cannot imagine how much I appreciate the effort and detail you put into this. I just learned heaps from a single read through. I'm sure I'll lean more tomorrow. Thank you again Nicholas, it's really motivating and inspiring to come across people like you in the dev community.